# How do i reply to a certain tweet using Tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to reply to create a code to reply to simply reply to a (given) tweet, i only know that api.update_status tweets but not how to reply to one, i did some researches but all are outdated and "in_reply_to_status_id" doesn't seem to work anymore

`api = tweepy.API(auth)`

```
api.update_status
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to reply to a tweet using the Twitter API `v2`, you need to use the `in_reply_to_tweet_id`. This works as follows.

```py
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key='YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY',
                       consumer_secret='YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET',
                       access_token='YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN',
                       access_token_secret='YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET')

client.create_tweet(text='Some reply', in_reply_to_tweet_id=42)
```

This is described in the documentation [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v4.6.0/client.html?highlight=in_reply_to_tweet_id#tweepy.Client.create_tweet).

> in_reply_to_tweet_id (Optional[Union[int, str]]) – Tweet ID of the Tweet being replied to.

**Edit:** If you are using API `v1.1`, then you need to include `@username` in the status text, where username is the author of the referenced Tweet. This is described [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html).

Hence, a working example looks as follows.

```py
comment = '@usernameOfTweet Test Reply'
res = api.update_status(comment, in_reply_to_status_id=42)
```

It is also possible to use `auto_populate_reply_metadata=True` as discussed in [this Github issue](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1267).

```py
comment = 'Test reply'
api.update_status(comment, in_reply_to_status_id=42, auto_populate_reply_metadata=True)
```

This is also described in the documentation.

> auto_populate_reply_metadata – If set to true and used with in_reply_to_status_id, leading @mentions will be looked up from the original Tweet, and added to the new Tweet from there.

Comment: i'm using Api v1.1

Comment: See my updated answer.